# getting issue in google chart while navigating to page numbers

Tags: html, reactjs

when we change page numbers in google chart table, why it removes aria-label attribute from its parent element in google chart?

I tried below approach

```
var buttons = chart
    .getContainer()
    .getElementsByClassName(goog - custom - button);

if (buttons.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].setAttribute("aria-label", "google chart");
    }
}
```